# Create tables on existing database

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am deploying `ASP.NET` project to a server and will work with a `mssql` server which I don't have permissions to create database.

The database has been created for me, I am his owner.

when I call `update-database` or when I run the application, it tries to create database and fails due to:

> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

I had like `EF` to just create the tables.

The normal initializers are:

```
CreateDatabaseIfNotExists
DropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges
DropCreateDatabaseAlways
```

All of these creates a database, which I don't have permission to do.

Is there an option to create tables from `Package Manager Console` something like `update-database` but without creating the database ?

**EDIT:** After searching a bit I found: `update-database -verbose -script` which I can use to generate table create scripts which I can run myself. But not in an automated way like `update-database`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null);
```

You can also go in the the `Configuration` class (which inherits from `DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyDbContext>`) and in the constructor specify:

```
AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
```

And, as you already found, you can use `-script` to generate the DB script and run it yourself.

Comment: I will test this initialization later, what should happen if the database does exists and empty ?

Comment: @Ofiris: Assuming EF passed the schema check (and can get to the __MigrationHistory table to verify) it should just plumb up nice and work.

Comment: What if the scheme changes? I can't run `update-database` as it tries to re-create the db.

Comment: @Ofiris: You would then, again, use the -script flag to generate the change script and apply it to your database. The other option is to allow the context account full owner rights to the db and let EF take care of it for you (it's designed to make non-threatening changes to the db without data loss) which would take the intermediary step out of the equation (while also allowing you to seed the database between changes).